# Grouping and counting occurences of a parameter within each group

Tags: linq, sqlite, group-by, linqpad

I'm fiddling with LINQPad and I'm sure this question has been asked but I've been struggling and searching for quite a while.

I have a collection like this:

```
Age  Material
---  --------
3    Steel
3    Steel
3    PVC
4    Steel
4    PVC
```

I want to group it first by Material, and then count the occurences of each Age within each Material group, resulting in something like this:

```
{Mat = Steel,
   [(Age = 3, Count = 2),
    (Age = 4, Count = 1)]}
{Mat = PVC,
   [(Age = 3, Count = 1),
    (Age = 4, Count = 1)]}
```

I know this has to do with nested groups but I can't get it right. I've been trying stuff like this (only without the question marks), but I don't know how to get to the items in each group:

```
var matGroups = from line in Pipelines                              
                group line by line.Material into matGroup
                from ???? in ???
                group ???? by ???.Age;
```

If its relevant, the data store I'm querying is in SQLite.

***UPDATE***

The following code gets me the data I want. However, I would still like to know the proper way to do this in a single query, if possible.

```
var materials = from p in Pipelines
                group p by p.Material into matGroup
                select matGroup.Key;

foreach (string material in materials)
{
    var ages = from p in Pipelines
               where p.Material == material
               group p by p.Age into ageGroup
               select new {Age = ageGroup.Key, Count = ageGroup.Count()};

    ages.Dump(material + " Pipelines");
}
```

Comment: I have never used LINQ, but the SQL command you want is simple: `select material, age, count(*) from pipelines group by material, age;` Maybe that will help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a grouping by `Age` and `Material`:

```
from p in Pipelines
group p by new { p.Material, p.Age } into g
orderby g.Key.Material, g.Key.Age
select new { g.Key.Material, g.Key.Age, Count = g.Count () }
```